# SQL Server 2008 - How to implement a "Watch Dog Service" which woofs when too many insert statements on a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

Like my title describes: how can I implement something like a watchdog service in SQL Server 2008 with following tasks: Alerting or making an action when too many inserts are committed on that table.

For instance: Error table gets in normal situation 10 error messages in one second. If more than 100 error messages (100 inserts) in one second then: ALERT!

Would appreciate it if you could help me.

P.S.: No. SQL Jobs are not an option because the watchdog should be live and woof on the fly :-)
      Integration Services? Are there easier ways to implement such a service?

Kind regards,
Sani

Comment: What would you be trying to achieve with the 'woof'? What columns do you have on the table? Ie. does it have a timestamp and incrementing key?

Comment: Woof could be SQL Statement, Mail to user, an action which notifies the sender to stop the inserts,...
Columns: 2 columns, one for PK and one varchar with error code.
No it doesn't have a timestamp or incrementing key (maybe one could describe PK as an incrementing key).

Comment: If the PK is fed from other inserts failing, then it probably isn't an incrementing key. Do you have any possibility of changing the data-model by adding a timestamp column to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your problem exactly, so I'm not entirely sure whether my answer actually solves anything or just makes an underlying problem worse. Especially if you are facing performance or concurrency problems, this may not work.

If you can update the original table, just add a datetime2 field like

```
InsertDate datetime2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Preferrably, make an index on the table and then with whatever interval that fits, poll the table by seeing how many rows have an InsertDate > GetDate - X.

For this particular case, you might benefit from making the polling process read uncommitted (or use `WITH NOLOCK`), although one has to be careful when doing so.

If you can't modify the table itself and you can't or won't make another process or job monitor the relevant variables, I'd suggest the following:

1. Make a 'counter' table that just has one Datetime2 column.
2. On the original table, create an AFTER INSERT trigger that:

   - Deletes all rows where the datetime-field is older than X seconds.
   - Inserts one row with current time.
   - Counts to see if too many rows are now present in the counter-table.
   - Acts if necessary - ie. by executing a procedure that will signal sender/throw exception/send mail/whatever.

If you can modify the original table, add the datetime column to that table instead and make the trigger count all rows that aren't yet X seconds old, and act if necessary.

I would also look into getting another process (ie. an SQL Jobs or a homemade service or similar) to do all the housekeeping, ie. deleting old rows, counting rows and acting on it. Keeping this as the work of the trigger is not a good design and will probably cause problems in the long run.

If possible, you should consider having some other process doing the housekeeping.

Update: A better solution will probably be to make the trigger insert notifications (ie. datetimes) into a queue - if you then have something listening against that queue, you can write logic to determine whether your threshold has been exceeded. However, that will require you to move some of your logic to another process, which I initially understood was not an option.

Comment: Thanks Anders for your quick and detailed answer.
I'm concerned about the database's performance if for every insert the trigger is fired. So I thought maybe there is a better solution instead.

Comment: The trigger writing in itself shouldn't be the problem. The problem will occur if you let it do a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Is there no other way of implementing this with triggers?
I mean let's assume you get 5000 error messages in one second and every insert fires a trigger which counts and checks all rows.

Comment: As I say in my update - the trigger should do as little as possible, ie. only insert into a queue or a table. So it all comes down to whether you will let another process do the work. If you're willing to let another process subscribe to the queue, I'd guess that would be your best bet as that would keep the trigger lightweight. If you can modify the original table to include the time of the insert, you can have another process monitor that and you won't have to create a trigger at all.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "another process monitor that"? I think that's what I need. Some process monitoring my table inserts. Let's assume I can change my table to store the time. 
I appreciate your time investing in my problem. thx!